Displaying the parameters passed to the function. Django\jinja
I'm at the beginning of learning django and jinja.
In the tutorials I see how the necessary data is transmitted when the button is clicked (onclick or click Listener). In any case if I open the elements via f12 I see the parameter values that are passed to the function. Is this method correct?
for example onclick="getName({{user.id}})" in f12 I will see the values user.id.
